# How to log wifi speed and strength?

Tags: wifi, macos

My wifi drops out multiple times per hour. It says it is connected but it goes to 1kb/s up and down and nothing works until I turn wifi off, then back on. Then it will work until it doesn't.

I want to log the speed and strength so I can diagnos and maybe use to convince my ISP that they have an issue (they provide the connection and the wireless router).

What app can log the speed and strength of a wifi connection? I googled but only found Windows bloatware type apps.

Comment: iStat Menus - https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

Comment: Try buying (cheap) dongle and use that as your WiFi adapter and see if problem persists. On my MPro 2014 it happens sometimes when I have cables (long 1.5m mouse cable, hdmi, random usb cables etc) on the lid - I use external display most of the time; can not determine cause but it seems to be weird design of antena.

Comment: This is why I use my own router and just get a modem from ISP

Comment: @Pratik I use iStats Menu. It is great but I need the historical log.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [Apple's own steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202663) on how to diagnose your WiFi connection. You can look specifically for [the report section](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202663#report) in that page, which explains how to and where to save the resulting data.

As a TL;DR, look in Spotlight for `Wireless Diagnostics` and click `Window` in the menu bar, there go to `Logs`.